# Translation of the game hide-and-seek

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, new-latin, roman-culture

According to Wikipedia, a kind of hide-and-seek-like games is attested in Ancient Greek as *apodidraskinda*.

Are there attested similar games in Ancient Rome? If not, are there any good options for the translation?